# Iptables rules for UFW

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ufw

I need the following rules implemented in UFW but don't know how to do this exactly:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
#Note: If you use tcp protocol you must change -p udp to -p tcp and --ddport 1194 to --ddport 443
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Note: If you use tcp protocol you must change -p udp to -p tcp and --ddport 1194 to --ddport 443
ip6tables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 2a01:4f8:c2c:5fc7:80::/112 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

How can I do this correctly?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copying existing rules verbatim you should learn to work with the UFW framework to achieve the desired effect.

Opening up specific ports is explained  in [`man ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ufw.8.html)

Setting up NAT and IP masquerading is explained in the manual [`man ufw-framework`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ufw-framework.8.html) and requires:

> ## IP Masquerading
>
> To  allow  IP  masquerading for computers from the 10.0.0.0/8 network on eth1 to share the  single IP address on eth0:
>
> Edit `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` to have:
>
> ```
>           net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
> ```
>
> Add to the end of `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, after the `*filter` section:
>
> ```
>           *nat
>           :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
>           -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>           COMMIT
> ```

For some more complex scenarios the UFW framework does not yet provide a good solution and for those use cases it supports loading "raw" iptables rules.

Comment: Thanks it seems ufw is not very reliable to config this scenario of configuration. Maybe I use ip(6)tables from the command line with iptables-persistent. For openvpn I don't know what else need to be configured, no other service will be installed so I want to block all inputs except ssh port. Need to look how I can do that the right way for ipv4 and ipv6, don't found any about this on the internet.